# Labeling date issue with graphview (android studio)

Tags: android, database

so far I was able to make graph with 4 dates but graph is showing today's date at left and showing future date (ex. if today date is 9/7/15, graph is showing date 9/7/15,9/8/15,9/9/15,9/10/15)

but what I want is showing today's date at right side and previous date at left side (ex. if today date is 9/7/15, graph is showing date 9/4/15,9/5/15,9/6/15,9/7/15)

this is my code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d2 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d3 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d4 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d5 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(d1, i),
            new DataPoint(d2, 5),
            new DataPoint(d3, 3),
            new DataPoint(d4, 2),
            new DataPoint(d5, 6)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);

    series.setValueDependentColor(new ValueDependentColor<DataPoint>() {
        @Override
        public int get(DataPoint data) {
            return Color.rgb((int) data.getX() * 255 / 4, (int) Math.abs(data.getY() * 255 / 6), 100);
        }
    });

    series.setSpacing(70);

    series.setDrawValuesOnTop(true);
    series.setValuesOnTopColor(Color.BLACK);

    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(MainActivity2.this));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(4);


    graph.getViewport().setMinX(d1.getTime());
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(d4.getTime());
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
```

also I want to save number daily(in my code the number that I want to save is "i")

so if I have integer 10 at 09/06/15, and 6 at 09/07/15, I want to save 09/06/15 data automatically(which is 10) when date is change and show at graph.

If you guys can help meout that will be great